# View3d operator is not available if there is no object selected. Why?

Tags: python, blender, operator-keyword

I'd like to create a pop-up window with some buttons. Here is the code:

```
import bpy

class MaxFloater(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.max_floater"
    bl_label = "MAX Floater"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width = 400)

    def draw(self, context):        
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
        row.operator("object.modifier_add", text="MIRROR").type='MIRROR'

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MaxFloater)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MaxFloater)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

All is fine, except that it expects some object to be selected, or last selected object to exist. If that object is deleted then the operator doesn't work. (and doesn't appear in the operator search window). I can't understand why is is so? This is a view3d operator, not an object operator, isn't it?

Comment: I tried to modify the poll function to always return True, and it solves the problem. But it seems to me that this is not the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the propper solution. This string should be in the poll function:

```
return bpy.context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D'
```

It checks that the currently active view is 3d view, and if not - the operator won't work.